# Stop displaying a camera sign in a Scene view in Unity

Tags: unity, camera, ide

How can I stop displaying a camera sign in a Scene view in Unity?

I mean that white thing you see below:

[image]

Comment: @TartleWizard I recommend posting that as an answer so the asker can accept it and mark the question as resolved. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your screenshot on the grey bar, look for the button "Gizmos". You can turn those icons on or off and make them smaller and larger.